Cannot find the language resource file dblgen11.dll
I have this method to test the connection between my application and a SQL Anywhere 11 database:
public static bool ProbarVinculacionEnkontrol(string nombreOrigen, string usr, string psw, int UsuarioOperacion)
{
    bool resultado = false;

    try
    {
        string con = $"ServerName=serv_v9;DatabaseName={nombreOrigen};UID={usr};PWD={psw};LINKS=tcpip(Host=MyIp:2630)";
    
        File.WriteAllText("E:\\conexion.log", con);
    
        using (SAConnection connection = new SAConnection(con))
        {
            connection.Open();
            resultado = true;
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("E:\\conexion.log", ex.ToString());
        Inserta.Error(ex, "consultaProbarVinculacion", UsuarioOperacion);
    }
    
    return resultado;
}

However, it always throws this error:
Cannot find the language resource file dblgen11.dll
Cannot find the language resource file dblges11.dll

I've looked everywhere but can't find the solution. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?


https://docs.appeon.com/2015/appeon_troubleshooting_guide/ch06s02s04.html
